# Join Many to many table in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5

I have two many to many table

1. Users(id, name,email)
2. reqs(req_id,quantity_req,status)
3. req_user(id, req_id,user_id)
   Is it possible to join those table so as to retrieve data

```html
     $u_id = $request->user_name;
 $start_date = $request->get('start_date');
$end_date = $request->get('end_date');
      $req = DB::table('reqs')
            ->join('req_user', 'reqs.req_id', "=", 'req_user.req_id')
 ->whereBetween('date_applied', [$start_date, $end_date])
            ->where('user_id', $u_id)
            ->pluck('req_id');
```

Comment: What is your question? What's wrong with this code?

Comment: it give me error SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'req_id' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: That's because two of your tables have the `req_id` column. The error is probably in your `->pluck('req_id')`. Change it to `->pluck('reqs.req_id')` and this error should be gone

Comment: return this Collection {#268 ▼
  #items: []
}

Comment: This means the query has no results